# Remove other OS which is installed alongside Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I have 3 OSs as a triple boot. They are as follows:
⠀Windows 8.1 Professional Edition
⠀Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr
⠀Elementary OS

All three OSs are installed in different partitions.

The problem is that the bootloader or Grub loading on startup is of Elementary OS and I want Ubuntu Grub to be loaded instead, so after that I can delete the Elementary OS partition and remove Elementary OS.

If I remove Elementary OS directly without changing the default Grub than on startup, Grub rescue mode will arrive and I hate that thing.

I hope you understood what I want. Please show me in steps or in a easy way.

Comment: When that Grub rescue mode appears you can try [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) and see if it will work. You'll need live CD or bootable usb.

Answer (score 0):

First, boot into a livecd just to be on a separate load disk, then delete the elementary OS partition. DO NOT reboot now, instead open a terminal and run "sudo update-grub /dev/sda" (replace sda with what the DISK, not PARTITION that you want; it will automatically add all available entries to the menu)

Comment: also, once you can boot into ubuntu normally I actually recommend burg bootloader, it seems to support windows better than grub

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but it created 2 windows 8 options in grub,one is in sda1 and another is in sda2.Moreover selecting any from these, it opens only one so i deleted the 2nd option from grub.cfg.. so it is also solved